# Does Angular update only one DOM element or all DOM element when interpolation is used

Tags: angular

Consider that  I have a child component with the following view template in Angular2 (or 4):

```
<div id="firstDiv">
<div id="secondDiv">
<span> {{someproperty}}</span>

<div>
</div>
```

And `someproperty` is a modified by the parent component using `@input` binding on the child. When the value of @input property changes, does the re-rendering of the child view happen at the div with the id of `firstDiv` or only at the `<span>` level?
In other words, does the whole shown structure get refreshed or just the `span` or just the text in the span?

Comment: Only text node with someproperty is updated if there Is any changes

Comment: I wonder why not just the innerText of the span tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the text node inside the `span` element will be updated using the renderer. Here is [the relevant code snippet](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/15090a8ad4a23dbe947ec48b581f1bf6a2da411e/packages/core/src/view/text.ts#L62) from the sources:

```
if (checkAndUpdateBinding(view, nodeDef, bindingIndex, newValue)) {
    value = text + _addInterpolationPart(...);
    view.renderer.setValue(DOMNode, value);
}
```

`DOMNode` here is the reference to the textNode.

For more details read [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)

Comment: Thank you! so <span> tag as oppose to just the text in the span tag!?

Comment: @Sean12, yeah, only the text node inside the span element will be updated. I added clarification to the answer.